# AngularError Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import the Observable class and the interval method and it's giving it to the terminal
[help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhup.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant code and the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the Observable prefix. So just remove it:

```
let time = interval(500);
```